# Is a flyback supposed to have infinite resistance on the secondary (arc) coil?

Tags: induction, flyback, coil

Previously, I was able to get nice arcs with the 555 timer and irfp450 MOSFETS. When they died out I thought it was just the FETS but when I went through the proper test procedure for the FETS, I noticed that they were OK. I was puzzled by this and I am now thinking I have a bad flyback. When I redid the whole circuit, I was able to make very TINY arcs (<2mm) and when I tried a ZVS, I got the same results. I then measured the primary and secondary coils with an ohm meter, and got strange results. The primary seemed o.k. with 1 ohm, but when I measured the secondary (where previously got arcs) , the ohms were at lest greater then 2 mega ohms (my meter goes up to 2M), and the only resistance i was picking up was my finger. Is this normal to have the arc coil (secondary) to have no resistance? Or is something wrong with my flyback, and what could've happened? All I know is I was running my arcs for 15 minutes straight before everything broke and I just want to confirm it is a bad flyback!

Comment: It sounds like your output coil has gone "open circuit"

Comment: so that it broke in one place or something?

Comment: Yes, your coil is broken.

Comment: YAY, SO EXITING!!! I am glad that it wasnt my driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i guess since I got answers in comments, I will just answer this myself. I do have a bad Flyback!!!

Answer (score 0):

"Is this normal to have the arc coil (secondary) to have no resistance?" Since, from the context, I take "no resistance" to mean infinite resistance, yes, many flybacks measure infinite (>2M) resistance across the HV secondary, especially if they have a built-in rectifier or tripler. You'll see some test procedures (and YT videos) using an approximately 20V power supply (2 9V batteries will do) and a volt meter for a crude idea of whether the HV path is open.